# How to disable rounded corners in Windows 11?

Tags: windows-11

I like the square corners of Windows 10 better. Also, screenshots will be easier with the square corners. But since it has been more than 10 days, there's no going back.

Answer (score 16):

[Win11DisableRoundedCorners [Github]](https://github.com/valinet/Win11DisableRoundedCorners/releases) provides a patch to uDWM.dll

It doesn't work on the start menu, but for applications.

Comment: Hey, it does work perfectly! Just a couple of bytes patch in 1 dll. Oogh, it was driving me nuts because video application was not rendering some pixels because of these corners. +1.

Answer (score 2):

Windows 11 will revert to square corners if you turn off
hardware graphics acceleration, which will unfortunately also turn off
other visual features like transparency.

Another (unrecommended) option is to ... disable entirely your
graphics hardware. In Device Manager, expand Display Adapters,
right-click your display adapter and Select "Disable Device".
The screen will flicker a moment but, when Windows returns,
the rounded corners will be gone. But so may also be gone the video
performance.

Answer (score 1):

Try [ExplorerPatcher](https://github.com/valinet/ExplorerPatcher) [GitHub]
The developer describes it as an all-around windows tweaker that "aims to enhance the working environment on Windows."

The project [Wiki](https://github.com/valinet/ExplorerPatcher/wiki/All-features#disable-rounded-corners-for-application-windows) has the following screenshots for removing rounded corners along with description of all of ExplorerPatcher's other features

[image: Default, rounded corners in Windows 11]
Default, rounded corners in Windows 11

[image: Sharp, 90-degree angle corners, as in Windows 10]
Sharp, 90-degree angle corners, as in Windows 10

**Warning**: On my PC (OS build 22000.1455), attempt to turn off rounded corners lead to elevation notification by User Account Control. I personally don't use this app because my OS built is not recognized by ExplorerPatcher, and Win+X and Start Menu don't work when I run it.

Comment: Right-click the task bar and choose: Properties → Other → Disable rounded corners for application windows

Answer (score 1):

A new, superior solution with no need to patch system files:

You can use the [Disable rounded corners in Windows 11](https://windhawk.net/mods/disable-rounded-corners) Windhawk mod.

First, download and install Windhawk from https://windhawk.net/. Then, go to "Mods" at the upper right, search for "Disable rounded corners in Windows 11" and install it.

Answer (score 0):

I have two Windows 11 machines: Production (1 month); Insider (5 months).

You cannot *natively* make the rounded corners square. Microsoft took away all customizations in the user interface so this is just the Windows 11 design and I suggest you adapt to it.

It is a case of: If Microsoft provided a way, you (we) can make changes; if they did not provide a way, then you (we) cannot.

It may change in future, but no sign of that yet.

There is an interesting article here on the fixed nature of Windows 11 (not specifically on rounded corners).

[Windows 11 fixed appearance](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/how-to-customize-and-use-windows-11-explorer)

Comment: Hmmm… have they copied the macOS look [again] yet failed to provide a screenshot tool that can use it? Mac window default screenshot type - https://i.stack.imgur.com/fK19t.png

Comment: Snipping Tool (and then loading into SnagIt) are traditional and have not caught up to the main Windows 11 interface.

Comment: Just wanted to have a mini rant about the fact that Microsoft have forced rounded corners on us like it's 2002, but not updated Outlook to handle it, so that some calendar buttons are now hidden by the round bezel.