# Any way to disable rounded CONTROLS (not windows!) in Windows 11?

Tags: windows-11, user-interface, win32, visual-styles

There are lots of utilities out there that allow you disable rounded corners of application *windows* in Windows 11, but I haven't been able to find anything that manages to also modify the visual styles to make ***controls*** (buttons, checkboxes, etc.) rectangular/square again.

Is there any way of doing this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable rounded corners in Windows 11?](https://superuser.com/questions/1688725/how-to-disable-rounded-corners-in-windows-11)

Comment: @DrMoishePippik No, it does not. The question itself is a bit vague but all of the answers relate to making *window* corners square again, not the *controls* inside of them.

Comment: https://www.pcworld.com/article/541452/make-windows-11-look-like-windows-10.html suggests turning off hardware accel, though that might apply only to window decorations, not buttons. Alternatively, install Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Stardock's WindowBlinds 11 will do this.  There is a free trial, so its worth a shot.

https://www.stardock.com/products/windowblinds/

I like their software.  I ***LOVE*** Fences.  I have used Groupy 2, as well.